# Rails 3: Route all POST to :update method for a specific namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest

Against the background of the PUT/PATCH/POST partial update discussion ( https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/505 ):

Actually I want to use the PATCH method in Rails but it is not yet implemented. So can I define (for a whole namespace) that THIS is standard behavior:

```
POST resource/:id => :update
```

?